# Gulp Watch doesn't detect changing in SASS SCSS folder

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

I have set up Gulp for the first time to compile SCSS to CSS using NanoCSS and gulp-css. 
I have created a do-sass that successfully compiles SCSS and minifies the CSS.
However, when I place this in a watch task, it does not work.
If I change any of my SCSS files the do-sass command does not run. Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');


gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('scss/styles.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
});

// Minifys .css and reload browser.
gulp.task('mini-css', function() {
    return gulp.src('styles.css')
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

// Compile and minify css.
gulp.task('do-sass', gulp.series('sass', 'mini-css'));


gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('scss/*/.scss', gulp.series('do-sass')); 
});
```

Comment: Perhaps your `watch` path is incorrect? `scss/*/.scss` makes me believe that gulp will look for nested SCSS files, and not any in the root directory. If you want to target any SCSS file then you need to use `scss/**/*.scss`

Comment: What's your directory structure? Why do you need to watch `scss/*/.scss`? Should this be `scss/*.scss`?

Comment: as @terry has mentioned, I believe it's supposed to be `'scss/**/*.scss'`

Comment: @JackBashford Its just a folder called scss at the moment. One test file to get it all set up

Comment: Glad I helped. I've taken my comment and rephrased it into an answer, with some additional explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

The glob pattern used by your watch task is probably incorrect: `scss/*/.scss` will not look for the SCSS files you want, because it will try to traverse one more directory deeper and look for files that are named `.scss` (without any file name, just the extension).

What you want is to use the [double-star](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/explaining-globs#special-character-double-star) syntax, if you want to glob *any* SCSS files that are nested at any level:

```
scss/**/*.scss
```

Therefore, if you update your watch task as such, it should work:

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('do-sass')); 
});
```